# How to delete a Watson CLI project?

Tags: macos, command-line-interface

I am using the [Watson CLI](https://tailordev.github.io/Watson/) to do project time tracking on MacOS High Sierra. I have two projects:

```
$ watson projects
project-a
project-b
```

The [`remove`](https://tailordev.github.io/Watson/user-guide/commands/#remove) command appears to only work at the frame level. For example:

```
$ watson remove project-a
Error: No frame found with id project.
```

However, listing the frames does not appear to be of any help in the effort to delete a project (e.g. project-a or project-b):

```
$ watson frames
d372d91
ba62bc3
77331fb
6a30d33
3033b1f
```

How can I delete one or all of the projects without having to guess which frames make up which project?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to find frames that are connected with single project by getting log of that specific project. You can do something like this:

```
watson log --project project-a
```

This will get you a list of all frames for particular project in last week (you can change time frame and get frame IDs for period you need) and on the left side of each frame you have ID that you can use to delete specific frame

Now when you remove all frames for single project, it will be deleted (this do not require any action except deleting all frames connected to project)

Hope this helps